# Create wp account contact type organization in civicrm

Tags: civicrm-contact

I'am using user registration processor to create a wp account which is connected to civicrm but the processor create contact type person by default. In my case i want to create contact type organization rather then person.
I've used email (unsupervised) as dedupe rule  but it doesn't work because the first type contact is organization and the second contact added by wp is person.

I'am asking how can i do this modification ?

thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear - are you talking about the User Registration processor for Caldera Forms? https://calderaforms.com/downloads/users/

Comment: Yes, i'am talking about it.

Comment: afaik civicrm is written so that the cms user can only be linked to an individual, based on the logic that an organisation is missing the fingers required to type the password. am sure folk have worked around this but that could be what is blockingi you

Comment: Yes, exactly what happen do you have an idea how can i solve it ?